# Two year columns when merging datasets

Tags: r

I want to make a linear regression of two sets of variables, so I merged them into one table, but two "year" columns show up. How can I only have one?

[image]

I used this code to merge my idelong and euexit data:

```
> fichierfinal<-merge (idelong,euexit, by= 1)
```

and tried to solve my issue with this one but it didn't work :

```
> datamerge<- idelong %>% right_join(euexit,by=c(1,2))
```

I would be very grateful for your help, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Help us help you by making your example [reproducible (and minimal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like both datasets contain a column called `name`. When you merge by `country`, both columns end up in the new dataset with ".x" and ".y" added for disambiguation.

If your observations are specific to a country-year combination, you will want to merge by `country` *and* `year` instead. That way you will not have duplicate `year` columns in your final dataset. Of course you will need to clean the respective `year` columns first so that they match each other (i.e., remove the "X").

Here is an example (not knowing exactly what your initial data looks like):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# define data
euexit <- tribble(
  ~country, ~year, ~scorepol,
  "Austria",  2019,  5.520714,
  "Austria",  2018,  5.867006,
  "Austria",  2014,   6.43598,
  "Austria",  2017,  4.910919,
  "Austria",  2015,  5.122485,
  "Austria",  2016,  6.251086
)

idelong <- tribble(
  ~country,   ~year,        ~fdi,
  "Austria", "X2014",  0.38685812,
  "Austria", "X2015", -2.08805654
)

# clean year columns
euexit <- euexit |> 
  mutate(year = as.character(year))

idelong <- idelong |> 
  mutate(year = str_remove(year, "^X"))

# merge
idelong |> 
  left_join(euexit, join_by(country, year))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   country year     fdi scorepol
#>   <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 Austria 2014   0.387     6.44
#> 2 Austria 2015  -2.09      5.12
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi, thank you I see the problem! However I don't know how to remove the X, since in my excel file there is no X in front of the years, but on R there is. Is there a code to remove it? Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the sample code I added.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to remove the X and now I still have two columns that are called year.x and year.y

When I run the code, to merge by country and year it says :

`Error in `left_join()`:
! Can't join `x$year` with `y$year` due to incompatible types.
ℹ `x$year` is a <character>.
ℹ `y$year` is a <integer>.`

Should I change y$year into a character? If so how?
I tried using `as.character(year.y)`but it didn't work.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Exactly as you describe - I included a line in my code above. The line you suggested doesn't work because you need to convert the column *before* you merge. At that point, the column is still called `year` rather than `year.y`.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen it. But even when I run everything, I still have an error telling me that the columns from each set do not match together :

idelong |> 
   left_join(euexit, join_by(country, year))
Error in `left_join()`:
! Join columns in `x` must be present in the data.
✖ Problem with `year`.

I checked, and the `year`column is present in my `euexit`  dataframe, so I don't understand. Sorry for all the questions, I'm just really lost. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Is it present in `idelong` too?

Comment: yes. I think it finally worked, I have a correct table that appeared in my console. However I would like it to be a data on its own, that I can open in my Environment. How can I make it "become a data" that I can use?

Comment: Right now I have this in my console :

> idelong |> 
+   left_join(euexit, join_by(country, name))
# A tibble: 162 × 4
   country name  `foreign direct investments` scorepol
   <chr>   <chr>                        <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Belgium 2014                       -2.84       1.64
 2 Belgium 2015                       -4.22       1.80
 3 Belgium 2016                       12.1        1.54
 4 Belgium 2017                       -7.42       1.22
 5 Belgium 2018                       -7.66       2.78
 6 Belgium 2019                       -3.99       2.53

...And it goes on.

Comment: Just save it as a new object: `merged_data <- idelong |> left_join(euexit, join_by(country, year))`

Comment: Thank you very much it's all good!

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark the answer as the accepted one if you'd like.